# How to display user account only using user ID num

Tags: c++

Im basically making a database that stores a users account info. (Name, Phone number, ID, etc) I want to be able to display a specific persons info by entering in their ID num.

I have a struct with basic info and an array struct that stores each person and their info. I need to be able to type in a persons ID and have it display their info.

(I am still in first year of CS degree plz be gentle lol)

```
struct Account{

string name;

string city;
string state;
int ZIP;
int phone;
int IDNUM;
double ACT_BAL;
string LST_PMNT;};
```

Main fuction

```
const int SIZE = 20;
Account customers[SIZE];
const int NEW_INFO = 1, CHNG_INFO = 2, DISP = 3, EXIT = 4;
char choice1; 
int choice;
int n;
int NEWCUST;
int results;
do
{   // menu display
    cout << "Customer Database\n"
        << "----------------------------\n"
        << "1. Enter new account info\n"
        << "2. Change account info\n"
        << "3. Display all account info\n"
        << "4. Exit\n";
    cin >> choice;
    //respond to user input
    switch (choice)


        case NEW_INFO:
            cout << "Would you like to enter a new cusomter?\n"
                << "(Y/N)";
            cin >> choice1;
            if (choice1 == 'Y' || choice1 == 'y')
            {
                cout << "How many new customers?" << endl;  //User eneters in new customer info without having to enter in a full array worth of customers. 
                cin >> NEWCUST;
                for (n = 0; n < NEWCUST; n++)
                {
                    cout << "ID Number: ";
                    cin >> customers[n].IDNUM;

                    cout << "Enter in a name: ";
                    cin >> customers[n].name;

                    cout << "City: ";
                    cin >> customers[n].city;

                    cout << "State: ";
                    cin >> customers[n].state;

                    cout << "ZIP code: ";
                    cin >> customers[n].ZIP;

                    cout << "Phone number: ";
                    cin >> customers[n].phone;

                    cout << "Account Balance: ";
                    cin >> customers[n].ACT_BAL;

                    cout << "Lasy payment date: ";
                    cin >> customers[n].LST_PMNT;



                }
            }
            break;
        case CHNG_INFO: // Changes info

            break; // displays all info (work in progress)
        case DISP:
            cout << "Enter customers ID number" << endl;
            cin >> customers[].IDNUM;
            results = linearSearch(customers, SIZE, customers[].IDNUM);

            break;

        case EXIT:
            cout << "Cosing......" << endl; //exits progeam
            break;
```

Comment: Since `IDNUM` is a unique key, you could use a `std::unordered_map<int, Account>` (where the `int` is the key/IDNUM) to store all accounts.

Comment: There are a few suggestions you can do to improve more in C++. You can use the classes instead of structs. Use enumerations to hold labeled constants (e.g. `NEW_INFO`, `CHNG_INFO`, etc.) This will make it more readable in future code.

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific user details, you can do the following:

Declaring `num` as `short int` to hold a simple User ID, you can change it. `N = 50` as you've provided the constant. Now, unless the loop finds the inputted ID matching with one of the struct's `idNum`, it'll be executed 50 times (max).

```
cout << "Input account code: ";
cin >> num;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (num == acc[i].idNum)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << acc[i].name << endl
             << "..." << endl;
    }
}
```